# how to display the array that depends on your choice?

Tags: java, eclipse

this is 1 method code.

```
import java.io.*;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] Ropher)throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

    String[] Accommodation = {"", "Standard Room", "Double Room", "Matrimonial Room", "Triple Room"}; // Accommodation
    double [] NightRate = {0, 500, 800, 1240, 1500};//Night Rate
    double GuestRate = 100; // Guess Rate
    boolean First = true, Second = true, Third = true, Fourth = true; // Loop
    int Standard = 4, Double = 4, Matrimonial = 4, Triple = 4;//Bed Types
    int SwitchOne, SwitchTwo = 0;
    String SwitchThree, SwitchFour, SwitchFive, SwitchSix;// For Switches
    String Anykey;// For The Condition Of Every Room
    String YesNo;// Yes Or No
    String SecretPassword = "151";//Secret Password
    int Option;//Options

    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------
     * Costumer's Information
     -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    do{//Start Of First Loop - Customer's Info
    System.out.print("\nEnter Number Of Records : ");
    int Records = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    SwitchOne = 0;
    String [][] Fullname = new String [Records][100];
    int [] Night = new int[100];
    int [] Guest = new int[100];
    int[] Confirm = new int [100];
    for (int x = 0; x < Records; x++){// Start For Records

    System.out.print("\nConfimation Number: ");
    Confirm[x] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    System.out.print("\nFirst Name: ");
    Fullname[x][0] = br.readLine();
    System.out.print("Last Name: ");
    Fullname[x][1] = br.readLine();
    System.out.print("Guest: ");
    Guest[x] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    System.out.print("Night: ");
    Night[x] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    System.out.println();

    do{// Start Of Second - Main Menu

        System.out.print("\n                             ||Main Menu||\n\n");
        System.out.print("|=====================================================================|");
        System.out.print("\n  ************************     Bed Types     ************************\n");
        System.out.print("|=====================================================================|\n\n");
        System.out.print("1. Standard..............................................P500.00\n");
        System.out.print("2. Double................................................P800.00\n");
        System.out.print("3. Matrimonial...........................................P1,240.00\n");
        System.out.print("4. Triple................................................P1,500.00 \n");
        System.out.print("5. Exit\n");
        System.out.println("\n   (WIfi, air conditioned room, LED TV, FREE BREAKFAST)");
        System.out.println("\t *Except Standard rooms and Double rooms");       

        System.out.print("\n\nPlease Select Room Type: ");
        SwitchOne = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

         //Start of Switch for SwitchOne - First Switch

        if (SwitchOne == 1){ //Standard - SwitchOne

            if ((Standard < 5) && (Standard > 1)){
                System.out.println("\n \t" + (Standard - 1) + " Standard Room Available");
                System.out.print("|---------------------------------------------------------------------|");
                System.out.print("\nOur Standard Room (1 Person) is ");
                System.out.print("exquisitely prepared bed linen,"
                        + "\nan interior bathed in warm light, "
                        + "\nand a relaxing bathtub in a sparkling clean bathroom. "
                        + "\nIn this atmosphere, guests are sure to feel the detailed attentiveness "
                        + "\nthat is the foundation of M.Y service.\n");
                System.out.print("|---------------------------------------------------------------------|\n\n");


            }else if ((Standard - 1) == 0){
                System.out.print("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------|");
                System.out.print ("\nRoom Not Available Right Now. \nPlease Try Again Next Time.");
                System.out.print("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------|\n\n");
                continue;   
            }


        }else if (SwitchOne == 2){ //Double - SwitchOne

            if ((Double < 5) && (Double > 1)){
                System.out.println("\n \t" + (Double - 1) + " Double Room Available");
                System.out.print("|---------------------------------------------------------------------|");
                System.out.print("\nOur Double Room  (2 Person) is"
                        + " most suitable for couples and the size"
                        + " \nenables you to relax and feel at home. "
                        + "\nAll rooms are also fitted with a desk, a closet and a washlet.");
                System.out.print("\n|---------------------------------------------------------------------|\n\n");

            }else if ((Double - 1) == 0){
                System.out.print("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------|");
                System.out.print ("\nRoom Not Available Right Now. \nPlease Try Again Next Time.");
                System.out.print("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------|\n\n");
                break;  
            }


        }else if (SwitchOne == 3){//Matrimonial - SwitchOne

            if ((Matrimonial < 5) && (Matrimonial > 1)){
                System.out.println("\n" + "\t" + (Matrimonial - 1) + " Matrimonial Room Available");
                System.out.print("|---------------------------------------------------------------------|");
                System.out.print("\nOur Matrimonial (2 Person) is ");
                System.out.print("one of our best features, "
                        + "\nwhere you can share with your beloved the unforgettable"
                        + "\nexperience offered "
                        + "by staying in our hotel.\n");
                System.out.print("|---------------------------------------------------------------------|\n\n");


            }else if ((Matrimonial - 1) == 0){
                System.out.print("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------|");
                System.out.print ("\nRoom Not Available Right Now. \nPlease Try Again Next Time.");
                System.out.print("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------|\n\n");
                continue;   
            }


        }else if (SwitchOne == 4){ //Triple - SwitchOne


            if ((Triple < 5) && (Triple > 1)){
                System.out.println("\n \t" + (Triple - 1) + " Triple Room Available");
                System.out.print("|---------------------------------------------------------------------|");
                System.out.print("\nOur Triple Room (3 Person) is ");
                System.out.print("deal for families and"
                        + "\nlarge enough to accommodate 3 people. "
                        + "\nThey also feature full private bath");
                System.out.print("\n|---------------------------------------------------------------------|\n\n");

            }else if ((Triple - 1) == 0){
                System.out.print("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------|");
                System.out.print ("\nRoom Not Available Right Now. \nPlease Try Again Next Time.");
                System.out.print("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------|\n\n");
                continue;   
            }

        }else if (SwitchOne == 5){
            System.exit(0);

        }else{// Default - SwitchOne
            System.out.print("\n>>>> Invalid Keyword! <<<<\n");
            continue;

        }//End of Switch for SwitchOne - First Switch

        if (SwitchOne == 1){

            do{//Start of Loop - Third Loop
                Second = true;
                System.out.print("\n1. Book.");
                System.out.print("\n2. Back.");

                System.out.print("\n\nPlease Select: ");
                SwitchTwo = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

                if (SwitchOne == 1){
                    Standard--;
                }

                if (SwitchOne == 2){
                    Double--;
                }

                if (SwitchOne == 3){
                    Matrimonial--;

                }
                if (SwitchOne == 4){
                    Triple--;
                }

                if (SwitchTwo == 1){
                    System.out.print("\nHave A Nice Day!\n");
                    Second = false;
                    break;

                }else if (SwitchTwo == 2){
                    break;

                }else{
                    System.out.print("Invalid Keyword!");
                    continue;
                }                                                                           

            }while (Third);//End Of Loop - Third

            }

        if (SwitchOne == 2){

            do{//Start of Loop - Third Loop
                Second = true;
                System.out.print("\n1. Book.");
                System.out.print("\n2. Back.");

                System.out.print("\n\nPlease Select: ");
                SwitchTwo = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

                if (SwitchTwo == 1){
                    System.out.print("\nHave A Nice Day!\n");
                    Second = false;
                    break;

                }else if (SwitchTwo == 2){
                    break;

                }else{
                    System.out.print("Invalid Keyword!");
                    continue;
                }                                                                           

            }while (Third);//End Of Loop - Third

            }

        if (SwitchOne == 3){

            do{//Start of Loop - Third Loop
                Second = true;
                System.out.print("\n1. Book.");
                System.out.print("\n2. Back.");

                System.out.print("\n\nPlease Select: ");
                SwitchTwo = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

                if (SwitchTwo == 1){
                    System.out.print("\nHave A Nice Day!\n");
                    Second = false;
                    break;

                }else if (SwitchTwo == 2){
                    break;

                }else{
                    System.out.print("Invalid Keyword!");
                    continue;
                }                                                                           

            }while (Third);//End Of Loop - Third

            }

        if (SwitchOne == 4){

            do{//Start of Loop - Third Loop
                Second = true;
                System.out.print("\n1. Book.");
                System.out.print("\n2. Back.");

                System.out.print("\n\nPlease Select: ");
                SwitchTwo = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

                if (SwitchTwo == 1){
                    System.out.print("\nHave A Nice Day!\n");
                    Second = false;
                    break;

                }else if (SwitchTwo == 2){
                    break;

                }else{
                    System.out.print("Invalid Keyword!");
                    continue;
                }                                                                           

            }while (Third);//End Of Loop - Third

            }       

    }while(Second);// End Of Second Loop - Main Menu        

    }// End For Records 
    System.out.print("\n\nList Of Customers:");

    for (int x = 0; x < Records; x++){

        System.out.print("\n|---------------------------------------------------------------------|\n");
        System.out.print("\n\nConfirmation Number:      |--------------->  " +   Confirm[x]);
        System.out.print("\nGuest Name:                 |--------------->  " + Fullname [x][0] + " " + Fullname [x][1]);
        System.out.print("\nNumber Of Guest:            |--------------->  " + Guest [x]);
        System.out.print("\nNumber Of Nights:           |--------------->  " + Night[x]);
        System.out.println("\nAccommodations:               |--------------->  " + Accommodation[SwitchOne]);
        }
    }while (First);//End Of First Loop - Customer's Info


}//IO
}//Body
```

The thing is when it displays the Customer's List it has the same Accommodation.

"System.out.println("\nAccommodations:               |--------------->  " + Accommodation[SwitchOne]);"

it must be display by the customer's choice.

and it must print after Records is done.

Please help me with this!

Comment: Please read about providing a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There is an awful lot of irrelevant code here.

Answer (score 0):

The error is selfexplained, you must initialize the variable SwitchOne.

```
int SwitchOne=0, SwitchTwo;
```

You have one error more in :

```
if (SwitchOne == SwitchOne) {//line 203
```

Comment: SwitchOne is user input.

if (SwitchOne == SwitchOne) then, SwitchOne + User Input .

if i initialize the variable SwitchOne then the Accommodation will not equal to SwitchOne .

What should i do ?

Comment: SwitchOne == SwitchOne, you are comparing two variables, this will be always TRUE because they are the same variable.

Comment: i got it. thanks .

But it doesn't fix the

"System.out.println("\nAccommodations:              |--------------->  " + Accommodation[SwitchOne]);"

Comment: what i want with that is see the customer's list along with the room they choose. any suggestion ?

Comment: If you change in your code (line 15) int SwitchOne, SwitchTwo;  with int SwitchOne=0, SwitchTwo;  your program will compile.

Comment: thanks i tried it.

The problem is if the Records is two then different Rooms the output is the same Room.

Comment: well, I suggest you to refactor all your code, using small functions for each menu. So you can test it better. Its hard to debbug your code now. And try to use loggers so you can trace your program flow, or an IDE with a debbuger (Eclipse)

Comment: And here is another error:

//line 78
Standard = 4;
if (Standard <= 4) { //this will be always true

Comment: I'm using Eclipse but i don't know how to use debugger.

Comment: I learned to use debbuger with this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html hope it helps. But, first of all, try to use differente methods for each "menu" in your program. Will help you a lot.

Comment: OK, prof rules :P. So just try to debbug your problem so you can find your errors :)